# C# how to implement a factory class which doesn't require an argument passed to indicate objects type?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, generics, factory-pattern

I currently working on a parser project in C# and have run into problem.

I have an entity folder within my project and within it I have:

```
Entity
  IEntity.cs (defines a contract for entity classes)
  Contact.cs (main entity class)
  Address.cs (struct for contact class to store address fields)
  EntityType.cs (enum of entities, i.e contact in this case)
```

My signatures for these types are as follows

```
public interface IEntity : IComparable

public class Contact : IEntity

public static class EntityFactory
 +public static IEntity GetEntity(string[] fields)
```

In order to deduct the type for the entity factory, I passed an enum into `public static IEntity GetEntity(string[] fields, EntityType.Contact)` and used switch statement to defer logic.

I plan to create more classes that will inherit from the IEntity class and that's why I want this to general enough to be able to be extendable.

Whilst the above approach works, it completely ruins the generic structure of my code and that's because I have another folder like so:

```
Parser
  IParser.cs defines general implementation requirements
  CSVParser.cs concrete type which implements those requirements
```

IParser.cs

```
public interface IParser<T> where T : IEntity
{
    T ParseToEntity(string row, EntityType type);
}
```

CSVParser.cs

```
    public class CSVParser<T> : IParser<T> where T : IEntity
    {
        public T ParseToEntity(string row, EntityType type)
        {
            string[] fields = FormatContact(row);
            T contact = (T)EntityFactory.GetEntity(type, fields);
            return contact;
        }
}
```

The issue here is that I don't want to be passing the type when I have T that's constrained to be of IEntity type. I somehow wan't to abstract this away. How do I go about this?

EDIT:
Posted an answer, though I still have questions. Why do I need to declare `IEntity newbObject` instead of `T newObject` considering i have `where T : IEntity` constraint?

Likewise, why do I have to cast to `(T)` the GetEntity method, considering I'm supplying it `T` generic that is also constrained to `IEntity`?

Comment: Get rid of the entity type enum and do `(T)EntityFactory.GetEntity(typeof(T), fields)` or `EntityFactory.GetEntity<T>(fields)` and switch on the actual type.

Comment: Factories return results that satisfy a shared, known interface. “Anything” is a poor target for a factory.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Hi, could you elaborate on how I'd go about switching on the actual type then? I tried the switching on typeof(T) and capturing the case typeof(Contact) but switch allows only constant expressions. Should I use if statement instead?

Comment: Figured it out with pattern matching in switch statement. Thank you both.

Comment: @Vocaloidas Since you figured it out, you might want to answer your own question so others can benefit from what you've learned.

Comment: To make it more likely to get some answers for your additional questions, I would try asking a new question. I would try to make this new question mostly self-contained (maybe add a link as an additional reference to this one), but write it in a way the gist can be understood without getting back here again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use switch pattern matching like so

```
public static IEntity GetEntity<T>(string[] fields)
where T : IEntity
{
    IEntity newObject;
    switch(type(T))
    {
        case Type typeContact when typeContact == typeof(Contact)
        //Do the object instantiation
    }

}
```

Then when I wanna create an object elsewhere I can just

```
T contact = (T)EntityFactory.GetEntity<T>(fields);
```

Comment: Since you're using generics, you can change the return type to `T`, as in `T GetEntity<T>(string[] fields)`, to avoid having to type cast, since you've constrained it to derivatives of IEntity (`where T : IEntity`).